# Check in bash if X server is running on resume/hibernation/boot

Tags: bash, xorg

I want to start a custom script as soon as my X is running. For now I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait until X server is running, indicated by a PID of XXX. Required only on first boot, not on resume.
X=$( pidof X )

while [ ${#X} != 3 ]
do
sleep 10
X=$( pidof X )
done

echo "Running autostart in 5 seconds..."

# Wait 5 seconds on resume before running.
sleep 5

# Do the rest...
```

This successfully waits until X is started on first boot. However, on resume X is already running and outputs a PID. Nonetheless I would want to wait until the resume process is completely finished. For now I can only think of a solution to sleep for a certain time. Are there other solutions?

Comment: If it's already running ... it's already running?

Comment: That's why I am asking for solutions that work with X on resume. Or in other words: How can I check whether the session was restored from suspension or hibernation>

Comment: You may want to check dbus messages to detect sleep/hibernate... & regarding X running or not: echo @tripleee :D